# UITableView rows

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uitableview, rows

I want to know how much is the table view row width and what is the font of a UITableViewCell text label, can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"width: %f", cell.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@"font: %@", cell.textLabel.font);
```

That logs the following with a "classic" tableview:

> width: 320.000000
>
> font:  font-family: "Helvetica"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 20px

Answer (score 2):

```
CGFloat cellHeight = cell.frame.size.height;
UIFont *labelFont = cell.textLabel.font;
```

table view cells have the same width as their table view.

Comment: the question does not ask about the cell height